# Tips app on iOS 8

Tags: ios

When I upgraded to iOS 8, I got a new Tips app about new features. However, none of the review sites mention this app, and I'm wondering if only some users got it, since it seems to be entirely pointless and I'd like to get rid of it. Can anyone confirm if everyone has this new app, and if there's any way of deleting it?

Comment: Just drop useless apps in a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everyone who upgraded to iOS 8 do have the "Tips" app. I have an iPad 2 and it also has "Tips". It's shipping with every build of iOS 8.

Sadly, you can't get rid of it unless you jailbreak your device.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the iOS 8 update so everyone has it and, unless/until someone like the developer of iOS6's HideApps creates an updated version, you will have to wait for a jailbreak or downgrade to iOS7 while you still can to get rid of it.